# why is the "Property buffer" being recognized as undefined?

Tags: typescript, multer

I'm trying to make a script that reads csv files and stores its information on a data bank,
but I'm getting notification of a problem that i dont know how to solve.

it says

> Property 'buffer' does not exist on type 'File | undefined'.

anyone who can explain it to me?
i'll be happy to post any other line of code that you can to understand better what is happening.

```
import multer from "multer";

const multerConfig = multer();

const router = Router();

interface Product{
    nome: String;
    nome2: String;
    nome3: String;
    nome4: String;
}

router.post(
    "/products",
    multerConfig.single("file"), 
   async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
        const {file} = request;
        const {buffer} = file
       
        const readableFile = new Readable();
        readableFile.push(buffer);
        readableFile.push(null);

        const productsLine = readline.createInterface({
        input:readableFile

        })

        const products: Product[] = []

        for await (let line of productsLine){
           const productLineSplit = line.split(",");
           

           products.push({
               nome: productLineSplit[0],
               nome2: productLineSplit[1],
               nome3:productLineSplit[2],
               nome4:productLineSplit[3],
           })
        }


      return response.json(products);
    }
);
export {router};
```

Comment: This looks like TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: The error indicates that the `request.file` object doesn't have a `buffer` property. Use `console.log(file)` to see what properties it has.

Comment: thanks for the help, yeah it is typescript, sorry.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/26mlaza